# Android AlertDialog freezes application some seconds after shown - cause seems OpenSL related

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-alertdialog, freeze, opensl

Ok I tried "everything" I could have found around and read everything I searched for, the question is quite simple yet I can't understand what the problem is.

I am working with the NDK ( Native code in CPP ).

I have a very simple Activity that has an OpenGL GLSurfaceView where some very simple rendering been done, at some point I would like to be able to open a simple AlertDialog with two buttons.

Now I tried many different approaches, fundamentally all falling into the idea of "a message
is posted to a Java thread which is there just polling for messages and then when it receives one it posts a message with a Handler to the main UI thread that runs a messages handler that creates the AlertDialog".

I tried a few other approaches including just doing - for test - "all from Java" by posting a message to the Handler inside the onTouchEvent() function of the GLSurfaceView like in the following code fragment :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

/* code to get the events .. */

           if ( maskedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN  && isUiOn == false)
           {
            isUiOn = true;
            GilesTest2JNIActivity.theHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
           }

return true;   
 }
```

The handler that receives the message does this :

```
public class GilesTest2JNIActivity extends Activity {

GilesTest2JNIView mView;
public static AlertDialog mTextInputDialog;

private Context MyContext;


public static Handler theHandler;


public LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

public Handler mHandler;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Log.i ("Giles OnCreate ","creating appl.");


    MyContext = this;


    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(MyContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 


        mHandler = new Handler(){     

            public void handleMessage(Message msg){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyContext);

                Log.i ("handler","builder");

                    builder.setView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null)); 

                builder.setTitle("User - Login");
                builder.setMessage("Please enter your username and pwd");


                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                            GilesTest2JNILib.nativeSendInputText( "BBB", "AAA");

                      //dialog.dismiss();

                        mView.isUiOn = false; // signal this is OFF

                        }
                     } );

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Log.w ("Keyboard","Kb is going away via CANCEL");
                    GilesTest2JNILib.nativeSendInputText( "**", "**" );
                    mView.isUiOn = false; // signal this is OFF

                  }
                });

                mTextInputDialog = builder.show();
                mTextInputDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


                mView.isUiOn = true; // signal this is ON


            }   
        };

 /* rest of onCreate() .. */
   }
```

What happens is the AlertDialog appears, all seems to be working ok but after some seconds everything freezes, there are no error messages, nothing, but even the rendering on the GLSurfaceView() stops as .step() is not called any more, everything just freezes to a halt without showing any error message of any kind and stays there almost forever and/or occasionally getting into "Application Not Responding".

This kind of behaviour seems to happen on the Nexus 7 tablet but on another tablet I have does not happen but after the 4th or 5th time I launch/close the dialog.

The only thing I managed to understand it seems something at some point stops receiving all sorts of touches and/or it's like "there's no window" and/or some window is disappeared, really I can't figure out what's going on.

I am re-adding some information I just found out after extensive testing.

After getting the classic basic OpenGL example, the one that simply draws a triangle and putting all that code back in found out it all works, so coming back to square one and re-trying the same on my code I started to put #ifdef in various places to chop away pieces of code until I found 'the crash point'.

After some time I found out this, it seems like the cause it's not in that piece of code at all but something has to do with the audio I have working in background.

It's a very simple player based around OpenSL and one player object where it continuously plays in loop a circular buffer where samples are mixed in, it seems that all boils down to this bit of code :

```
 // at this point we can enqueue the current chunk for playing

  theSize = AUDIO_DATA_CHUNK_SIZE*sizeof(SLint16);

  #define DO_NOT_ENQUEUE 1

  #ifndef DO_NOT_ENQUEUE

  result = (*bq)->Enqueue(bq, (void*) curdata, theSize ); /* Size given in bytes. */

  #endif
```

AUDIO_DATA_CHUNK_SIZE is 128, that thing is designed to play in loop a circular buffer where samples are mixed in, it plays constantly ( sample rate 11.025 Khz ).

If I disable playing sounds while the Alertdialog is up everything works flawlessly.

No idea really what's going on except at some point you can see this happening :

```
  12-19 18:56:52.418: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(303): Timed out waiting on     IInputContextCallback
  12-19 18:56:52.418: I/InputDispatcher(150): Dropped event because it is stale.
  12-19 18:56:52.418: I/InputDispatcher(150): Dropped event because it is stale.
  12-19 18:56:52.418: I/InputDispatcher(150): Dropped event because it is stale.
```

It seems that in some way the audio playing interferes with input.